# celery task does not terminate

Tags: python, celery

I've created a task where the program uploads a file and the task acts as expected i.e it successfully uploads the file but even after the task does its work, the task does not "terminate", the state still remains PENDING. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

From [the celery docs](http://ask.github.com/celery/userguide/tasks.html#pending):

> PENDING: Task is waiting for execution or unknown. Any task id that is
>   not know is implied to be in the pending state.

Are you sure the task finishes what it does cleanly? Best to post code.